# Updating one table based on values of another

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Let me know if I totally fail at making sense here, I'm trying I really am. What I would like to do is write an update query to change a value in my story_tbl based on a count of approved chapters with the same story_id on my chapter_tbl.

So basically, if a story has no approved chapters then in the story_tbl it should not be approved.

I've tried a few things, but so far I can tell I am making this way more complicated than in needs to be. Some help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will set all stories with no approved chapters as not being approved:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE story_tbl SET approved = 'n' WHERE story_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT story_id FROM chapter_tbl WHERE approved = 'y')");
```

These two queries will de-approve all stories, then approve all stories with at least one approved chapter: (basically a slower and more long winded way of doing the same thing, but with the benefit of also approving stories with chapters that are approved)

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query("UPDATE story_tbl SET approved = 'n'");
$this->db->query("UPDATE story_tbl SET approved = 'y' WHERE story_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT story_id FROM chapter_tbl WHERE approved = 'y')");
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: just a quick question in my database my approved is either 'y' or 'n' does your 0 mean no and your 1 mean yes?

Comment: It works! I am jumping up and down in joy, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE story_tbl AS story SET story.approved = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM chapter_tbl AS chapter 
    WHERE story.id = chapter.story_id AND chapter.approved=1
    GROUP BY chapter.story_id)
```